# Rails 6 how to link subfolders in assets/config/manifest.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6

I just upgraded to Rails 6 and followed guides to make this manifest file:

```js
//= link_tree ../fonts
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

But rails complains that I haven't added assets from `/images/subfolder/`

How do I link to `/images` and everything under it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    //=link_tree ../images
```

Since this is already doing the setting up of the subdirectory for you, just have to set the image tag correctly.

so in an image tag it would be:

```
    <%= image_tag image_url('balloons/balloons.jpg') %>
```

to create a clickable link with an image tag embedded would be:

```
    <%= link_to image_tag(image_url('balloons/balloons.jpg')), image_url('balloons/balloons.jpg') %>
```

You can also use the image as a background image in css, if you're using scss with the asset_url helper

```
.bg-container { 
  background-image: asset_url('balloons/balloons.jpg');
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;  
}
```